# How to display time along the top in FullCalendar?

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar

FullCalendar is a great-looking library, and I'm wondering if there is an existing way to display time along the horizontal axis across the top of the calendar for day views. If there isn't, where do I start a display plugin to display events horizontally rather than vertically?

Comment: That is not available in the fullCalendar 1.5 yet. I was trying to do this for many days and because of the way the calendar is rendered- it is impossible. I have not found any plugins either

Comment: The only other way to do it is to use jquery and insert your own divs to the elements that you want from an event that is loaded. But i have no example for you , sorry.

Comment: @ppumkin: Thanks for the comment, sounds like it may be a hopeless task, at least until FullCalendar makes some changes. Thanks for saving me hours of frustration! ;)

Answer (score 0):

i believe this is sort-of what you are asking...

http://code.google.com/p/fullcalendar/issues/detail?id=150

(not implemented yet)

Comment: Basically, yes, though I don't so much need the gantt-style resource stuff as much as something like what hipmunk.com does, with the vertical axis used for separating out overlapping events.